# Pyspark Java java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: pyspark, azure-data-factory, databricks

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 
   
df_customer_account_statement = df_current_balance.select\
    (
        col('last_statement_close_balance').alias('beginBalance'),
        col('current_statement_close_balance').alias('closeBalance')
    )\
    .withColumn('documentType',lit('RewardAccountStatement'))\
    .withColumn("statementBeginAt",  lit(current_statement_begin_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]+'Z'))\
    .withColumn('statementCloseAt', lit(current_statement_close_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]+'Z'))\
    .withColumn("uuid", F.expr("uuid()"))
```

The last withColumn throws null pointer exception.

Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: is it possible that "current_statement_begin_date" or "current_statement_close_date" are null?

Comment: The problem appears to be with 'current_statement_begin_date' or 'current_statement_close_date'. Please provide additional information regarding the same so that we can proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

The 'z' and 'Z' are used to represent the time zone in date time format. Use the below code block

```
strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

instead of

```
strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]+'Z'
```